# Stream reading from database using spark streaming

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I want to use spark streaming to read data from RDBMS database like mysql.

but I don't know how to do this using JavaStreamingContext

```
 JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.milliseconds(500));
DataFrame df = jssc. ??
```

I search in the internet but I didn't find anything

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do it like that without installing some third party piece of software.
What you CAN do is creating a personalized receiver which does what you want, using the SparkSQL package and the Streaming one combined.
Implement a class extending Receiver and inside do all the connections and querys needed to pull the data from the DB.
I am at work now, so I'll give you a link to see instead of producing the code, sorry:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html
https://medium.com/@anicolaspp/spark-custom-streaming-sources-e7d52da72e80

Answer (score 1):

The best possible and reliable solution would be avoid using MySqL at all. when you insert your records to MySQl put them also into Kafka (Kafka producer) by a transaction and then use them in your streaming application.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to stream from MySql I think. Data can be ingested from many sources like Kafka, Flume, Twitter, ZeroMQ, Kinesis, or TCP sockets.

Comment: no, I want to select for each x seconds the newest data from my database. I m sure that this is is possible, but I m a newbie in spark so I don't know how to do it

Comment: I already use rabbitmq between source and storm, but storm should save the data into my database, then spark read it from the database to do his works

Comment: also its impossible to use brokers between database and spark

Comment: using spark and storm together is rather duplication. It's difficult to find solution if i don't know you data pipeline :) I think you should use rabbitMQ as input for spark and skip storm and mysql. You can use https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-RabbitMQ. MySQL can be output for spark.

Comment: Now there is a big difference between a storm and spark, Storm works on events and spark use micro-batch, also spark has some package for machine learning. in my use case storm receives data from rabbitmq and organize this data, then spark should read from the database using micro-batch to run his machine learning library. so I must use spark streaming to read from database

Comment: I think you can use spark to think you are using storm. Less technology in our data pipeline is better for further maintenance :)

Comment: I know, for my use case, the best solution to get a high performance is to use both technologies. but even if used only spark,will need to use in memory database to insert my data (hundred of sensors types), then i will need to use (select x where timeserises ...) for machines learning

Comment: Why in memory ? You can use for example Cassandra for storing sensor events. I don't think  mysql scales well for big data.

Comment: In fact, I'm using Cassandra and in memory database, using in memory database help to avoid the famous problem of stream processing which is "congestion", but I don't let the data in-memory database forever, (in-memory database = buffer)